# How to manually configure logging in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I have my own code for configuring logging (logback):

```
val appender = // complex appender logic
val context = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory() as LoggerContext
val rootLogger = context.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)!!
rootLogger.addAppender(appender)
```

how can i plug this code into spring? ideally i would like to get some properties using spring and then use those properties to build the `appender`